# Dynamically Generate View By Web.Config Parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, multilingual

I'm developing a multi language web application with ASP.NET MVC. But some languages will be optional. For example users see two textbox on the screen. One of them for English and other's for French. I want to create dynamically the textboxes by web.config.  If "ActiveLanguageList"  in the web.config has a language code so the application create a textbox for the language. But i can't create it dynamically from my view model. I have to write HTML helper manually.  I want to create them dynamically with a loop or etc... Because one different thing is country code in HTML page. For example "ContentNameEn", "ContentNameFr"
Thanks for your suggestions.

```
//in my setting class
var ActiveLangs = new List<string>(); //For example EN,FR

//in web.config
<add key="Languages" value="EN,FR"/>

//in my view model
[DisplayName("English Content Name")]
public string ContentNameEn { get; set; }

[DisplayName("French Content Name")]
public string ContentNameFr { get; set; }


//in myview
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="ContentName">Content Name(EN)</label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ContentNameEn, new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ContentNameEn)
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="ContentName">Content Name(FR)</label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ContentNameFr, new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ContentNameFr)
    </div>
</div>

 //i want to code in the view like this but i can't
 @foreach(var langCode in ActiveLangs){
   //i need here create langCode's html code with htmlhelper
   //@Html.TextBoxFor
   //@Html.LabelFor
 }
```

Comment: Are you saying you always have a textbox for `ContentNameEn` and `ContentNameFr` but then you may have others for say German, Spanish etc?

Comment: I mean that. One language is required. But other languges can be optional. If ActiveLangs has "EN,FR,GR" there is threee textbox. if it has one language there is one textbox. if it  has 10 languages so i need 10 textbox. ContentNameEn, ContentNameFr, ContentNameSpa, ContentNameGer  etc...

Comment: Then you really need a view model to represent this so that you can get 2 way model binding - it would contain properties `string LanguageCode` and `string ContentName` and then you create a collection of the view model to use in the view and use a `for` loop to generate the controls (including a hidden input for the language code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have an unknown number of textboxes to generate, your model needs to be a collection. You view model should be

```
public class ContentVM
{
  public string LanguageCode { get; set; }
  public string LanguageName { get; set; } // used for the label
  [Required]
  public string ContentName { get; set; }
}
```

Then in the controller, create a collection. Note that your method of storing the code in `Web.Config` may need to change to allow you to store the language name as well (an xml file may be a better solution). For example

```
List<ContentVM> model = new List<ContentVM>();
foreach (var language in ...)
{
  model.Add(new ContentVM(){ LanguageCode = language.Code, LanguageName = language.Name };
}
return View(model);
```

and then you view would be

```
@model List<ContentVM>
....
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
  for(int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
  {
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].LanguageCode)
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m[i].ContentName, Model[i].LanguageName)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].ContentName)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m[i].ContentName)
  }
  <input type=submit" ... />
}
```

and in the POST method

```
public ActionResult Edit(List<ContentVM> model)
{
  // loop through the collection to get each ContentName and the associated LanguageCode
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create an attribute which specify that a property must be displayed only if defined in web.config.

Set this attribute on all your "ContentName" properties.

Use reflection to recover all your model property which contain this attribute. For each property, check if the associated code is present in the web.config, and generate the corresponding html textbox.

Example (without html generation) : https://dotnetfiddle.net/RRvC6K